# Substituting variable into SQLAlchemy / Postgresql Query

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run a SQLAlchemy query in my Flask app using. I want to grab the URL parameter ('menu') and substitute it's value into my query...

```
@app.route('/attend/')
def attend_by_role():
    role = request.args.get("menu")
    attendee_by_role = session.query(Attendee).filter_by(role = True)
    return render_template("attending.html", attendee = attendee_by_role)
```

This is directly looking for `role` in my table, which I don't want. I want to look up what the `role` variable is as defined by the URL parameter.

Comment: For example if `role == 'admin'` you want only the entries that have `'admin'` as a role?

Comment: My table has several columns (i.e. frontend, backend, design, admin), all of which have Boolean entry values. I want to run a query so that `role` represents the column name and returns only the rows where the entry values are True (in that column). This is probably simple but I'm new to SQL Alchemy!

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter by the column specified by the `menu` parameter? Try `.filter_by(**{role: True})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a dictionary to get the value of `role`.

```
attendee_by_role = session.query(Attendee).filter_by(**{role: True})
```

Alternatively you can use `filter` instead.

```
attendee_by_role = session.query(Attendee).filter(getattr(Attendee, role) == True)
```